# How to import existing PHP project into Eclipse without creating .project files in project folder

Tags: php, eclipse, import

I am trying to do something which should be trivial. I would like to import an existing PHP project into Eclipse. I have my workspace directory elsewhere from my project directory. I would like Eclipse to keep the `.project` and other Eclipse files in it's own workspace without polluting the project folder.

The only options that Eclipse provides is `Create project at existing location (from existing source)` and that is **not** what I want.

How can I do this?

Comment: I think that's the only cleaner way exists as of now.